codeIgniter, Main connection [MySQLi]: Access denied for user '****'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
I have an issue, I want to connect to a database with codeIgniter.
my connection configuration in app/config/Database.php is :

class Database extends Config
{
/**
* The directory that holds the Migrations and Seeds directories.
*/
public string $filesPath = APPPATH . 'Database' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

/**
 * Lets you choose which connection group to use if no other is specified.
 */
public string $defaultGroup = 'default';

/**
 * The default database connection.
 *
 * @var array<string, mixed>
 */
public array $default = [
    'DSN'          => '',
    'hostname'     => 'localhost',
    'username'     => 'codeI',
    'password'     => '1234',
    'database'     => 'DBSite',
    'DBDriver'     => 'MySQLi',
    'DBPrefix'     => '',
    'pConnect'     => false,
    'DBDebug'      => true,
    'charset'      => 'utf8mb4',
    'DBCollat'     => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    'swapPre'      => '',
    'encrypt'      => false,
    'compress'     => false,
    'strictOn'     => false,
    'failover'     => [],
    'port'         => 3306,
    'numberNative' => false,
    'dateFormat'   => [
        'date'     => 'Y-m-d',
        'datetime' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
        'time'     => 'H:i:s',
    ],
    'ssl_verify'   => true,
];



The user "codeI" is define and I can use it in my command shell :

projet3a@projet3a-OptiPlex-5050:~$ mariadb -u codeI -p1234
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 58
Server version: 10.6.16-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-log Ubuntu 22.04
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'codeI'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for codeI@localhost                                                                                                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO codeI@localhost IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A4B6157319038724E3560894F7F932C8886EBFCF' REQUIRE SSL WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,000 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]>

I saw my log file but I saw nothing usufull

2024-05-15 14:49:57 55 [Warning] Access denied for user 'codeI'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2024-05-15 15:13:43 56 [Warning] Access denied for user 'codeI'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have already connect to this bdd with a python program :


charger le fichier de configuration (load the configuration file)
    with open(fichierConfig) as config_file:
        config = json.load(config_file)
    # Blockquoterecuperer la configuration de la base de donnée (get the database configuration)
    database_config = config.get('mariaDB')
    # Connexion à la base de donnée (connect to the database)
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=database_config.get('host'),
        user=database_config.get('username'),
        password=database_config.get('password'),
        database=database_config.get('database')
    )
    # Création d'un curseur pour exécuter des requêtes SQL (create a cursor to execute SQL queries)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    # insertion de la tache dans la base de donnée (insert the task into the database)

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Taches (id, nomTache, nomUtilisateur, dateDemande, dateFin, statut, descriptions, aplicationSource) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, NOW(), NULL, %s, NULL, %s)", (id, 'initCompte', idUtilisateur, 'Initialisation', 'Intranet'))

    # Valider la transaction
    connection.commit()

    # Fermeture du curseur
    cursor.close()



I don't know what to do, I hope anyone may help me, thanks in advance
I tried, change permision of my database user
add and remove line

    'ssl_verify'   => true,


test with an other database in my localhost
test with port in hostname like this :

    'hostname'     => 'localhost:3306',


[edit]
I tried a new thing :
I tried with ssl_verify = false and with ssl disabled in mariadb, and that not fixe the issue
also I tried just use pdo with this code :
<?php
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=DBTaches", "codeI", "1234", [
    ]);
    echo "Connexion réussie !";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Échec de la connexion : " . $e->getMessage();
}

and I have an error.

I create a user "debug@%" with all privilège but no REQUIRE SSL and that works so the issue is due to ssl
